# how to convert array to objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have got array of objects.

```
   const data = [ {group: [{label:"1"}]}, {topGroup: [{label:"12"}]} ]
```

I want to convert array to this format of object

```
 let permission ={
   group:["1"],
   topGroup:["2"]
 }
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: ___In JavaScript, almost "everything" is an object.___ : *w3schools*

*BUT.. BUT.. BUT...*, Expected output can not be an object. It is _Unexpected token_

Comment: Hi Sujon, your array do not seem well-formed. Should it be more like : ```const data = [
  {group: ["1"]},
  {topGroup: ["txt","ss"]}
]```

Comment: An object requires a key and value pair and the expected object has none...??

Answer (score 2):

Based on:

```
   const data = [ {group: [{label:"1"}]}, {topGroup: [{label:"12"}]} ]
```

Afterwards, you have a bunch of options to achieve this, I would suggest this approach using `Object.assign`:

```
let permission = Object.entries(
  Object.assign({}, ...data)
).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: value.map(({ label }) => label),
}));
```

The output:

```js
const data = [ {group: [{label:"1"}]}, {topGroup: [{label:"12"}]} ]

let permission = Object.entries(
  Object.assign({}, ...data)
).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: value.map(({ label }) => label),
}));
console.log(permission)
```

For more information about `Object.assign`, [check this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Comment: @HMR what would be output : if it is input  let data = [{group:[{label:"ss"}]}]

Comment: @sujon I've updated my answer with the output.

Comment: I edit my question based on your answer

Comment: Haha, I've also edited my answer based on your edits @sujon

Comment: it doesn't work  . I see there is a label with output

Comment: Ouptut will be {
 {group:["1"]},
{topGroup:["txt","ss"]}}
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210093/discussion-between-sujon-and-hmr).